# Why can't const functions in Rust make calls to associated functions?

Tags: static, rust

This:

```
const fn pow2(exp: u32) -> u32 {
    u32::pow(exp, 2)
}
```

Results in a compiler error:

```
error[E0015]: calls in constant functions are limited to constant functions, struct and enum constructors
```

Is there a way to do this?

I'd like to do:

```
pub const MY_BITMASK: u32 = pow2(4);
```

Comment: because pow is not constant ?

Comment: There's no such concept in Rust as a "static fn", there is only "const fn".

Comment: @Shepmaster In some literature, I see Thing::method() referred to as "static methods", e.g. https://rustbyexample.com/fn/methods.html

Comment: @marathon thank you for pointing that out. Those are called [associated functions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#associated-functions). I'll see about a PR to fix that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A const function cannot call a non-const function. This is because const functions need to be able to run during compilation, so they can't call a non-const function which can only be evaluated at runtime. Since `u32::pow` is not a const function, you can't call it from a const function.

The question now becomes: Why isn't `u32::pow` a const function? And the reason for that is a current limitation of const functions: They can only contain a subset of the language. Notably, they can't contain loops or assignments. Since [`u32::pow` uses both of these](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.19.0/src/libcore/num/mod.rs#L1084-L1104), it can't be marked as `const` and therefore can't be called from const functions.

Note that there isn't any limitation of calling associated functions from const functions, as long as the associated function is marked `const`. And `u32::pow` is not an associated function in any case: you can call it as e.g. `x.pow(y)`.

**Update:** Const functions [gained](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2020/08/27/Rust-1.46.0.html) a lot more language features they can use in Rust 1.46 (including `if`, `while`, `&&`, etc.), and the integer types' `pow` functions were made `const` in [Rust 1.50](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/02/11/Rust-1.50.0.html).

Comment: Update on this: hopefully as Miri is integrated into rustc more, more things will become possible and many more functions will be able to be marked `const`